# MS SQL Server - OpenXML - Multiple elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml, sql-server-openxml

XML example:

```
<POLICY>
    <RISKS>
        <RISK>
            <DRV>1</DRV>
        </RISK>
        <RISK>
            <DRV>2</DRV>
        </RISK>
    </RISKS>
</POLICY>
```

I want to select both Risk elements with this query:

```
SELECT RISK
FROM OPENXML(@hDOC, 'POLICY/RISKS', 2)
WITH(
    RISK            XML     'RISK'
) AS Z
```

Expected:

```
1. <RISK><DRV>1</DRV></RISK>
2. <RISK><DRV>2</DRV></RISK>
```

Result:

```
1. <RISK><DRV>1</DRV></RISK>
```

(only first element was returned)

For comparison this query returns two rows as expected:

```
SELECT DRV
FROM OPENXML(@hDOC, 'POLICY/RISKS/RISK', 2)
WITH(
    DRV         XML     'DRV'
) AS Z
```

Result:

```
1. <DRV>1</DRV>
2. <DRV>2</DRV>
```

So the question is how can I get two Risk-rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you not using the native `XQuery` support provided by **SQL Server**. `OpenXML` is old and having lot of issues.

You can write your query like following using `XQuery` Support

```
DECLARE @hDOC xml   
SET @hDOC='<POLICY>
    <RISKS>
        <RISK>
            <DRV>1</DRV>
        </RISK>
        <RISK>
            <DRV>2</DRV>
        </RISK>
    </RISKS>
</POLICY>'  
SELECT T.c.query('.') AS result  
FROM   @hDOC.nodes('/POLICY/RISKS/RISK') T(c)  
GO
```

You will get output as

```
1. <RISK><DRV>1</DRV></RISK>
2. <RISK><DRV>2</DRV></RISK>
```

**Edit**: If you still want to do with `OpenXml`, use query like following.

```
DECLARE @DocHandle int 
DECLARE @hDOC VARCHAR(1000)   
SET @hDOC=N'<POLICY>
    <RISKS>
        <RISK>
            <DRV>1</DRV>
        </RISK>
        <RISK>
            <DRV>2</DRV>
        </RISK>
    </RISKS>
</POLICY>'  
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @hDOC 
SELECT RISK
FROM OPENXML(@DocHandle, 'POLICY/RISKS/RISK', 2)
WITH(
    RISK XML     '.'
) AS Z

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle
```

You will get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a lot of existed code in the project implemented with OpenXML and I just don't want to implement this part with XQuery.